# dataframe to frozenset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, frozenset

I want to translate a dataframe to frozensets and keep the dataframe columns within the frozenset.

Example

```
x=pd.DataFrame(data=dict(sample=["A","B","C"],lane=[1,1,2]))
>>> x
   lane sample
0     1      A
1     1      B
2     2      C
```

And I would like something as :

```
x2= {frozenset({("sample", "A"), ("lane", 1)}),
    frozenset({("sample", "B"), ("lane", 1)}),
    frozenset({("sample", "C"), ("lane", 2)})}

>>> x2
{frozenset({('sample', 'B'), ('lane', 1)}), frozenset({('sample', 'A'), ('lane', 1)}), frozenset({('lane', 2), ('sample', 'C')})}
```

I tried `x.apply(frozenset,1)` but it gives me that :

```
0    (1, A)
1    (1, B)
2    (C, 2)
dtype: object
```

Any help will be useful.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your dataframe to the `records` format you need with `pd.DataFrame.to_dict`:

```
x.to_dict('records')

# [{'sample': 'A', 'lane': 1}, 
#  {'sample': 'B', 'lane': 1}, 
#  {'sample': 'C', 'lane': 2}]
```

Since this results in a list, you can then map `frozenset` to the list like so:

```
# using abbreviation 'r' instead of 'records'
map(lambda y: frozenset(y.iteritems()), x.to_dict('r'))

# [frozenset([('sample', 'A'), ('lane', 1)]), 
#  frozenset([('sample', 'B'), ('lane', 1)]), 
#  frozenset([('sample', 'C'), ('lane', 2)])]
```

Or, using a set comprehension, if your output should be a set of frozensets:

```
{frozenset(y.iteritems()) for y in x.to_dict('records')}

# set([frozenset([('sample', 'C'), ('lane', 2)]),  
#      frozenset([('sample', 'B'), ('lane', 1)]), 
#      frozenset([('sample', 'A'), ('lane', 1)])])
```

Comment: I tried your last solution but have an error :
`{frozenset(y.iteritems()) for y in x.to_dict('records')}`
Here's the error :
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <setcomp>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems' `

Comment: @NicolasRosewick change `iteritems` to `items` if you're using python3. The set comprehension would then be `{frozenset(y.items()) for y in x.to_dict('records')}`